# Adaptive websites - considered keyword stuffing by Googlebot?

Tags: seo, css, keywords, blackhat, responsive-webdesign

I work on a SEO-dependent content website, and we are in the process of making our site [adaptive/responsive](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/). More technically, we are using CSS media queries to apply different CSS styles as the size of the browser changes.

As the browser size shrinks to 320x480 and below (mobile), we use CSS to hide much of the content on the page - up to 75% of it.

My question is - would Googlebot consider this practice keyword stuffing? My worry is that Googlebot may think we are stuffing the page with keywords to make the page relevant, but then hiding the keywords with CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googlebot doesn't have a "viewport size." It's going to see whatever your default layout is.
Assuming you're set up with Webmaster Tools, try out the "[fetch as Googlebot](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=158587)" feature. There are some third party tools that try to approximate this(search for something like "view as googlebot"), but this is obviously the official reference tool, so you might as well use it.